# How to add textboxes as records in a while loop in PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to add textboxes dynamically in a while loop in PHP.

Example:

```
$sql = oci_parse($c, "select temporada, jornada, partido, equipo_local, equipo_visita, 
nvl(pronostico, 'G') pronostico, nvl(resultado, 'E'), nvl(prono_modalidad, 'F') prono_modalidad, 
nvl(resultado, 'E') resultado from table_name where temporada = '$temp' and jornada = $jorna order by 
partido asc");

oci_execute($sql);
while ...
<tr>
<td style="width: 2%; text-align: left;"><?php echo $row["TEMPORADA"];?></td>
<td style="width: 1%; text-align: center;"><?php echo $row["JORNADA"];?></td>
<td style="width: 1%; text-align: center;"><?php echo $row["PARTIDO"];?></td>
<td style="width: 1%;"><?php echo $row["EQUIPO_LOCAL"];?></td>
<td style="width: 1%;"><?php echo $row["EQUIPO_VISITA"];?></td>
<td style="width: 1%; text-align: center;"><?php echo $row["PRONOSTICO"];?></td>
<td style="width: 1%; text-align: center;"><?php echo $row["PRONO_MODALIDAD"];?></td>
<td style="width: 1%; text-align: center;"><?php echo $row["RESULTADO"];?></td>
<td style="width: 1px; text-align: left;"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success 
editbtn">Editar</button></td>
```

Over here I will add 32 columns for textboxes.

It will iterate for 9 records, so I will have 32 textboxes as columns and 9 textboxes as rows = 288 textboxes.

How can I add these textboxes dynamically? With Javascript and PHP.

Thanks in advance.

Kind regards,

Francisco Mtz.

Answer (score 0):

The use of while is not meant for this, you need to do a foreach instead and return your table.

```
//declare a variable that can be populated with your data
$html = '';
foreach($sqlQueryResult as $key => $row){
$html = '<tr>
<td style="width: 2%; text-align: left;">'.$row["TEMPORADA"].'</td>
<td style="width: 1%; text-align: center;">'.$row["JORNADA"].'</td>
<td style="width: 1%; text-align: center;">'.$row["PARTIDO"].'</td>
<td style="width: 1%;">'.$row["EQUIPO_LOCAL"].'</td>
<td style="width: 1%;">'.$row["EQUIPO_VISITA"].'</td>
<td style="width: 1%; text-align: center;">'.$row["PRONOSTICO"].'</td>
<td style="width: 1%; text-align: center;">'.$row["PRONO_MODALIDAD"].'</td>
<td style="width: 1%; text-align: center;">'.$row["RESULTADO"].'</td>
<td style="width: 1px; text-align: left;">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success 
editbtn">Editar</button></td></tr>';

}
return /* or echo */ $html;
```

Hope it works for you.